# Dictionary retrieval of value for key IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I am sorry i am new to IOS,i couldnt figure out the solution to this problem

This is just a beginner restaurant menu

There is a tableview containing items and price and when i click one item,it displays another view where the user has to input the quantity and click a done button,so when the user clicks done i want to multiply the quantity times the price,how do i retrieve that particular price and multiply it with the quantity user input in the textfield.

Here's my code

I have declared NSDictionary in the Menu header file called

```
NSDictionary *dict;
```

My viewdidload method

```
dict=[[NSDictionaryalloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
@"TomatoSoup",@"20.00",@"VegManchowSoup",@"12.00",nil];
NSLog(@"%@",dict);
[super viewDidLoad];
```

I have displayed this contents in a table view

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [[dict allKeys]count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ 
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

NSArray *sortedkeys=[[dict allKeys]sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSString *key=[sortedkeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *value=[dict objectForKey:key];
cell.textLabel.text=value;
cell.detailTextLabel.text=key;
return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{
if(indexPath.row==0){   

VegQuantity *vegetarian1 = [[VegQuantity alloc]   initWithNibName:@"VegQuantity" bundle:nil];
vegetarian1.m_SelectedIndexPath=indexPath.row;
vegetarian1.pass=dict;
[self presentModalViewController:vegetarian1 animated:YES];
}
if(indexPath.row==1){   

VegQuantity *vegetarian1 = [[VegQuantity alloc] initWithNibName:@"VegQuantity" bundle:nil];
vegetarian1.m_SelectedIndexPath=indexPath.row;
[self presentModalViewController:vegetarian1 animated:YES];
}
}
```

VegQuantity.h
There is a View that has a textfield and a button saying done,
now when I click the done button I need to retrieve the value for that particular soup and multiply it with the number of quantity I input.
My problem is how am I supposed to retrieve the price(value) for that particular key and multiply it with the quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You retrieve a value from a Dictionary by using.

```
[dict objectForKey:@"someDummyKey"];
```

But to be honest. You should use a NSMutableArray as datasource for you UITableView and not a NSDictionary.

Comment: If i use NSMutableArray how can i retrieve the particular price for the particular soup

Comment: You will have to make a Dictionary for every dish. Containing key value pairs with keys price and name and the corresponding values.
Then in 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' you just have to pass the dictionary contained in the array to your veggi-class. You will know which array by using 'indexPath.row'. Inside your Veggi-Class you can then access the correct dish and use the data.

Comment: The value from the textfield you can get by simply accessing the textfield.text. You should not forget to create float values from the strings contained in the Dictionary and the textfield. Otherwise your multiplication would fail. :)

Comment: i have done the same thing above,i have passed the dict value along with indexpath.row but i want to know how do i access that particular value for that particular dish? NOTE: i have the indexpath.row value as well as dictionary,all i want to know is how to access that value of the dictionary for the selected dish and use it to multiply with the quantity

Comment: Well you pass the dish to your class you are using for your modalViewController. In that class you could just use [pass objectForKey:key] but since you dont know which dish, you don't have the key and thus you cannot get the value. Thats why i said you should use an array containing dictionarys with keys name and price and the corresponding values.

Comment: Unless I'm much mistaken you need to change that line of code to [dict objectForKey:@"someDummyKey"];

Comment: Maverick1st thanks man you helped me..but now i dont know how to display the array of dictionairies in UITableView thanks once again..:-(

Comment: To display the content of the array just grab your dictionary in the cellForRowAtIndexPath and set the cell content like this:
cell.textLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];

cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"price"];

Comment: hey thanks one last help,plz you have been really grateful..this code is in my done button NSNumber *prices=[pass objectForKey:@"price"];NSNumber *quantity=input.text;NSNumber *results=(quantity)*(prices);output.text=result;  i am getting invalid operands,i know i have to type cast nsstring to nsnumber but i really dont know what should i do i about it..

Comment: Note: i have taken two textfields input and output just to display the calculations

Comment: You set a NSNumber as value for your Price, just as graver mentioned.
For multiplying purpose you don't need nsnumber, you can just make all your variables as float and multiply just as usual. To display the result in output.text just use:
output.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", result];

Answer (score 2):

```
dict=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                     @"TomatoSoup",@"20.00",@"VegManchowSoup",@"12.00",nil];
```

The method is initWithObjectsAndKeys, which means first is the object then key, (key "20.00", object - "TomatoSoup") - in your case it's the opposite.

Second, instead of having an NSString for the price (I suppose it's price or quantity) use NSNumber - [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20.0f].

Then, make your VegQuantity view controller (btw it's good idea to call it VegQuantityViewController, in order to keep the naming conventions) 2 properties:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *itemName; //Use strong if using ARC,  otherwise retain
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *price;
```

and pass those values to the view controller before you show it. Then inside it you can do whatever you want with them.
  P.S. It's a good practice to use properties to manipulate the values of the instance variables.